# How to pass data from html to django view to use in URL?

Tags: html, django, view

I'm getting an error while working with django urls. I want to pass the value of Name input field after i hit the submit button.

Let's say I've this html form-

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'submittedform' slug=[firstname] %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div>
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="useremail" id="email">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for=phone>Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phone" maxlength="12" pattern="[0-9]{10}">
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" name="" id="btn" value="Submit">
                    </form>
```

Here's my view that handling it-

```
def submittedform(request, slug):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do something here
        return render(request,'myapp/welcome.html')

    return render(request,'myapp/welcome.html')
```

and here's my view that's handling it-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/',views.index ,name='index'),
    path('welcome/<slug:slug>/',views.submittedform, name='submittedform')
]
```

I'm not using django forms. How can i get welcome/name working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable to an URL you need redirect with the value:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect("/welcome/%s/" % slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```html
<!-- Removed the bracket -->
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'submittedform' slug=firstname %}">
    <!-- Children tags here -->
</form>
```

Now the variables are accessible in view like

```
def submittedform(request, slug):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        # and more variables as you need
        # do something here

        # do redirect here or give some message that their form has been
        # submitted for their confirmation 
        return render(request,'myapp/welcome.html')

    return render(request,'myapp/welcome.html')
```

Comment: It didn't work. I got the error NoReverseMatch at /geeks/index/. Reverse for 'submittedform' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['geeks/welcome/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Comment: I don't have an issue in accessing variable. I'm getting confused in how to any of those input fields value pass to 'welcom/xyx/' url.